# Is there a way to get a reference to see the remaining time left in a Local Notification, and have it update?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, usernotifications

I would like to show the user the remaining time left before the local notification is called. I can display the time, but it will not update. Is there a way to get the remaining time left in a local notification to update? Here is part of the code.

```
func notificationCall() {

    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
    if granted {
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()

        content.title = "Ready for the QOTD"
        content.body = "You have 1 min to answer the question"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: 86400, repeats: false)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "myTrigger", content: content, trigger: trigger)

        center.add(request)
```

If I print out timeInterval, I receive the original time of 86400, instead of it being updated. I tried using a timer to sync with the Notification, but you run into a host of other issues if the app goes into background or get's terminated. Any advice or solutions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you also save the date the notification was setup and then compare that date to now?

Comment: That is a good idea. I'll try that out. Could you possibly give me an example of it? Lastly, it seems to be a good solution, but still curious if you can actually access timeInterval and see the remaining time left without creating  another stored variable and comparing it.

Comment: As for whether it's possible to get the time interval remaining, I'm not sure. An example would just be to save the current date to user defaults and then check against that date with the current date to see how much time is left.

Answer (score 0):

UIApplication's has property called [scheduledLocalNotifications](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/scheduledLocalNotifications)

```
NSMutableArray *notifications = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[notifications addObject:notification];
app.scheduledLocalNotifications = notifications;

UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
NSArray *eventArray = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
for (int i=0; i<[eventArray count]; i++)
{
    UILocalNotification* oneEvent = [eventArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDictionary *userInfoCurrent = oneEvent.userInfo;
    NSString *uid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userInfoCurrent valueForKey:@"uid"]];
    if ([uid isEqualToString:uidtodelete])
    {
        //Cancelling local notification
        [app cancelLocalNotification:oneEvent];
        break;
    }
}

NSArray *arrayOfLocalNotifications = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] ;

for (UILocalNotification *localNotification in arrayOfLocalNotifications) {

    if ([localNotification.alertBody isEqualToString:savedTitle]) {
        NSLog(@"the notification this is canceld is %@", localNotification.alertBody);

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:localNotification] ; // delete the notification from the system

    }

}
```

Hope this helps to get the notification details, else you will have to save the details of notifications in the userdefault, then compare the time scheduled with the current device time and the result will be the time left